# Java Reference incorrect

Tags: java, methods, reference

i'm using OWL-S API (source and javadoc here: http://on.cs.unibas.ch/owls-api/apidocs/ )

If i do this i have the correct result:

```
public class Example {
    private static ISWRLFactory factory; //is a interface
    private string url = "http://...";
    private Service aService;
    private OWLOntology ont;

    void method_A(){
            URI aURI = URI.create(url);
            OWLKnowledgeBase aKB = OWLFactory.createKB();    
            aService = aKB.readService(aURI);
            ont = aKB.createOntology(aURI);
            ont.createService(aService.getURI());

    }

    void method_B(){
    factory = SWRLFactory.createFactory(ont);
    Atom builtAtom = factory.createNotEqual(x, variab); //x and variab are two variable
    }
   }
```

But if i do this i don't have the correct result:

```
public class Example {
    private static ISWRLFactory factory; //is a interface
    private string url = "http://...";
    private Service aService;
    private OWLOntology ont;


    void method_A(){
            URI aURI = URI.create(url);
            OWLKnowledgeBase aKB = OWLFactory.createKB();    
            aService = aKB.readService(aURI);
            ont = aKB.createOntology(aURI);
            ont.createService(aService.getURI());
            factory = SWRLFactory.createFactory(ont);
    }

    void method_B(){
    Atom builtAtom = factory.createNotEqual(x, variab); //x and variab are two variable
    }
}
```

Why?

Comment: Could you point out what are the differences between them? I don't want to dig into the code..

Comment: When do you call method_A vs method_B?  And how do you know that the results are different?  What's different?

Comment: @Math in the first example i do all the operation in one method, in the second case i do some operation in one method and the other in another method, then i call before the first method, then the second.. But i haven't the some result if i have all operation in one method!

Comment: @HotLicks in another method i call first method_A(), then method_B().. The result is different, because i do other operation and last operation is write in a file the result.. But if i do like the second example in the file i haven't all the information!

Comment: I solved it, I do not know exactly how I did it, because I made a long series of changes

Answer (score 0):

Difference exist in executing " factory = SWRLFactory.createFactory(ont);" line in method_A() and method_B().
Are you sure 'factory' object is not modified between method_A() and method_B() calls? Does 'x' and 'variable' have some dependency on 'factory' ?

Comment: yes, i am sure that "factory object" is not modified.. No, x and y haven't dependency..

Comment: I solved it, I do not know exactly how I did it, because I made a long series of changes